# big calendar react Can we have multiple color on different dates of Month?

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

big calendar react Can we have multiple color on different dates of Month?

Suppose: Every Date on month will have different color according to its events.

Comment: Could you be more specific about your problem?

Comment: I have calendar control, i want to have different color on different dates.
Like: 

1 March Red Color to full Box
2 March Blue Color to Full Box
3 March Grey Color to Full Box

Answer (score 0):

The [dayPropGetter](http://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#prop-dayPropGetter) does allow you to set styling in the month view, according to date, but it does not have access to other calendar props (like `events`)

Method signature:

```js
(date: Date) => { className?: string, style?: Object }
```

Usage:

```js
const dayPropGetter = (date) => {
  // build some className from the `date` and/or
  // build some style definition from the `date` data
  return { className, style }
}

<Calendar dayPropGetter={dayPropGetter} />
```

So, if you wanted to highlight every Wednesday, or weekend days, or 'today' in some manner, you could use this to do that.